# Check if return is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return, nonetype

Is it efficient to do this in python3?

```
if request_link(requested_domain, requested_link) is not None
    domain_res, link_res, r_res = request_link(requested_domain, requested_link)
    parse_results(domain_res, r_res)
```

Does this mean that interpreter will look into the same function twice?

Is it efficient? If not, what is the better way to check if the function returns none and act upon the result?

thank you!

Comment: Yes, it means the function will be executed twice

Comment: Assuming the interpreter didn't run that function twice, how should it know that the same value is returned on the second call? Your question basically answers itself if you think about it for a while...

Answer (score 4):

Name the result?

```
ret_value = request_link(requested_domain, requested_link)
if ret_value is not None
    domain_res, link_res, r_res = ret_value
    parse_results(domain_res, r_res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing the return to a variable seems to be the fastest and most natural way. Thanks a lot!

Case closed! :)

Btw, wtf is with those quality requirements?! Can’t I just say what solved the problem and thank people?! I’ve upvoted all the answers that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just store the return result before the if statement:

```
res = request_link(requested_domain, requested_link)
```

if res is not None:
domain_res, link_res, r_res = res parse_results(domain_res, r_res)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you called the same function twice and probably it's not efficient unless python magically detects that u called this function before and preserve the output to prevent a duplicate call. 
from what I see, Its sounds your request_link function  returns a None or a list containing domain_res, link_res, r_res, but if I want to do this, I do it as below:

```
def request_link(requested_domain, requested_link):
    ...
    if desired_otput:
        return True,domain_res, link_res, r_res
    else: 
        return False, None, None, None
```

and then in the main function:

```
result = request_link(requested_domain, requested_link)
if result[0]:# this means that results are not none
    #do what you want with result[1], result[2] , result[3]
```

this is the way you wouldn't have to call the function twice